# redirect issue on webconfig file

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

please check sfveinaesthetics.com/index.php opens but http://sfveinaesthetics.com/ dont.. its a wordpress site in iis7 server.

inner pages work http://sfveinaesthetics.com/about-us/ fine..

Please get a me solution asap.. web config is like

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's causing the problem but the default rewrite rule for Wordpress does not include the `/{R:0}` part in the rewrite action. Normally it's:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
```